# Issues with passing a variable with jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var id = $.urlParam('id');

    var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;

    $.post("api.php", { id: id });

    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                        
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'json',                      
      success: function(data)          
      {
        var path = data[0];         
        alert(path);
      } 
    }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a variable in the URL called id (for example http://www.url.com?id=1) and I'm trying to send it to a page called api.php where I have the database query. Then I'm trying to get the corresponding value of this id (in my case path) and return it. However it seems that the variable id is not being passed to api.php. I have hardcoded the id variable in api.php ($id = 1), the query is working fine and after that I'm able to get the value from the database, but when in api.php I put the following:

```
<?php

  if($_POST) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
  }

?>
```

Then it's not working. I'm not sure if the $.post() method is not working or for some reason I'm not able to get the value of the id variable in the PHP script.

Can somebody help me to solve this out?

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: You define `id` twice in JS. If you look at ajax request is the value there?

Comment: `$.ajax()` does a get request, not post. that means $_POST will **NOT** be set when you do your .ajax() call.

Comment: can't use `$.urlParam('id')` if you haven't included that plugin function in page. Will throw exceptions and break your code. Also you have back to back ajax requests...the second with no data and a GET and the first one has no done callback

Comment: You missed the .ajax option `type : 'post'`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet not to mention any data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `$.post()` call has no callback, so even though the POST request is made, there is no code to execute when it's successful.

Your second, `$.ajax()` call does not specify a `type` parameter (or any data for the call), and as a result will use `GET`. Inside your `api.php` file, you're checking the `$_POST` super-global, which of course does not contain the value for `id`, since you're using `GET`, not `POST`.

You should update your `$.ajax()` call as follows:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'api.php',                        
    data: { 'id': <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?> },                        
    dataType: 'json',   
    type: 'post'               
}).done(function(data) {  
    var path = data[0];         
    alert(path);
});
```

(You don't need the first `$.post()` call, I think you have confused the usage of this function).

Also, you'll need to actually output something from `api.php` in order to access it in JS, for example:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['id']) )
{
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @khan Huh? I'm fully aware that `$.post()` has a callback, but the OP did not specify one in his code... That explains why he doesn't see anything happening when the AJAX request is done.

Comment: Sorry i missed **your** while reading the first line of your answer. Upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I think you may be confused.

`$.post()` is a shortcut method for using the full `$.ajax`. You use one or the other, not both together.

To use `$.post` you need a callback for the data returned

Try removing `$.ajax` and doing

```
$.post("api.php", { id: id })
    .done(function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
```

Now in your php you don't show any output to the page.

So try:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['id']) ) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     echo $id;
  }

?>
```